# I want to update Item in dynamo db using UpdateItem API but it creates if item not exists

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

What i have to do i am using `UpdateIemRequest` and hit to `UpdateItem Api` in request i put the condition to update the item but if the item is not present in  the table so it has to create new one but it return error `ConditionalCheckFailure` if i remove the condition Expression so its work fine but i have to give condition Expression it has to create new item if not present in table

```
{TableName:ITEM_TABLE,Key:{RANGE_KEY={S:0,},ITEM_ID={S:G!!,}},ReturnValues:ALL_NEW,UpdateExpression:setVERSION=:val1,ConditionExpression:VERSION<=:val1,ExpressionAttributeValues:{:val1={S:B,}}}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `ConditionExpression`? Try performing the update only if ConditionExpression `attribute_exists` is true

Comment: if i add conditionExpression it not insert item it will return exception ConditionCheckFailure